# how does Unity implements Vector3.Slerp exactly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For my research I need to know, how exactly Unity implements the Slerp function for Vector3.

The [Unity3D documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Slerp.html) descripes, that the input vectors are treated as directions rather than points in space. But it doesn´t explain, if there are quaternions used intern.

The Unity3D-C#-Reference mentionied Vector3.Slerp [here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Math/Math.bindings.cs):

```
[FreeFunction("VectorScripting::Slerp", IsThreadSafe = true)] extern public static Vector3 Slerp(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, float t);
```

However, I cannot find the definition anywhere. I think it´s a **C++** Reference. Unity's C++-Code is only available with a licence (as far as I know).

**Can someone help me determine this question? All I need to know is if Unity3D internally uses  Quaternions for Vector3.Slerp(Vector3, Vector3, float).**

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp has a couple of different formulas so use, one might be what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I have to know, what form Unity3D is using and If ```Vector3.Slerp(Vector3 a, Vector3b, t)``` is internally using quaternions. 
I think in theory the formula should work with Vectors as well, but I have to be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm of course not sure because we don't have the source code for these internal methods but I'm pretty sure they would not use `Quaternion` which would be pretty imperformant but rather use pure and simple float based math like sinus, cosinus etc something that in `c#` would look somewhat similar to e.g. the solution mentioned [here](https://keithmaggio.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/math-magician-lerp-slerp-and-nlerp)

> ```
> Vector3 Slerp(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, float percent)
> {
>      // Dot product - the cosine of the angle between 2 vectors.
>      float dot = Vector3.Dot(start, end);
>
>      // Clamp it to be in the range of Acos()
>      // This may be unnecessary, but floating point
>      // precision can be a fickle mistress.
>      Mathf.Clamp(dot, -1.0f, 1.0f);
>
>      // Acos(dot) returns the angle between start and end,
>      // And multiplying that by percent returns the angle between
>      // start and the final result.
>      float theta = Mathf.Acos(dot) * percent;
>      Vector3 RelativeVec = end - start * dot;
>      RelativeVec.Normalize();
>
>      // Orthonormal basis
>      // The final result.
>      return ((start*Mathf.Cos(theta)) + (RelativeVec * Mathf.Sin(theta)));
> }
> ```

Though theirs are of course in the underlying c++ environment and won't use `Mathf` and therefore should be a bit better in performance.

Comment: thank you! I also think so, but I was confused due to the amount of found Slerp-descriptions for Quaternions. 
The formulas should work well with Vector3, so there is no good argument for unity to implement the function with intern quaternions.